# iframeでhtmlを取得したいが、取得したhtmlの中身(cssや画像)は取得させたくない。

Tags: javascript, html, http

HTML/JavaScriptのiframeタグについてご教授下さい。

■実施したい事
iframeでhtmlを取得したいが、
取得したhtmlの中身(cssや画像)は取得させたくない。

■詳細イメージ
①
iframe

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/sample.html"></iframe>
```

↓
②
WEBブラウザが `http://example.com/sample.html` へGETリクエストを投げて、
レスポンスが返ってくる
↓
③
WEBブラウザが返ってきたレスポンスをDOMツリーにロードする
↓
④
WEBブラウザが `http://example.com/sample.html` に記載されているcssや画像を取得する

①②は実施させて、
③の前後で処理を中断させて、
④を実施させたくない。

■質問事項
上記を実現させるためにはどのようなHTML/JavaScriptの実装が必要でしょうか？
ご教授下さい。

■思うところ
③のタイミングでイベントを発生させて、
④を無効にするような処理が可能かな？と調べてみましたら、
「DOMContentLoaded」というDOM読み込み完了後に呼ばれるイベントがあったのですが、
うまく使えますでしょうか。

また、タグ等を動的に発行して、
取得したhtmlを無効に出来るかな？と思っています、
うまく使えますでしょうか。

また、ブラウザで発生するHTTPリクエストを全てキャッチして、
`http://example.com/sample.html` に記載されているcssや画像のHTTPリクエストを遮断できないかな？と思っています、いかがでしょうか。

その他、手段は問いません。
実現できる方法をヒントだけでも良いのでご教授下さい。

Comment: 取得したいURLは別ドメインですか？

Comment: 同ドメインも別ドメインも両方用途があります。
何か関係があるのでしょうか？

Comment: ちょうど回答でも言及されているように、AjaxでHTMLだけ取得することを考えたのですが・・・同ドメイン（正確には同一オリジン or CORSがよしなにされている）でないと無理です。

Comment: Ajaxでは難しそうですね。
やりたい事は質問の通りなのですが、
別の方法がないものでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

### 要約

- 読み込むページと別オリジン（別ドメイン）のリソースだけブロックすればいい場合
  → iframe の sandbox 属性
- あらゆるリソースを完璧にブロック、するのは iframe では難しい

  - 親ページと読み込むページが同一オリジン → XMLHttpRequestでHTMLだけ取得
  - 別オリジンでCORSも使えない → サーバーサイドに頼りましょう

---

### HTMLの読み込みの検知

[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) はそもそも、外部リソースの読み込み**完了**を待たないだけで、外部リソースの読み込みを開始する前とは限りません。実際、DOMContentLoadedでブレークポイントを仕掛けても、すでにいくつかのリクエストが飛んでいました。

また、DOMContentLoaded イベントを使うには対象の Document オブジェクトにアクセスしないといけないのですが、これは iframe の読み込みの途中で作成されます。これに関するイベントはないので、[タイマーで監視して、作成されたらすぐさまイベントを設定する](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24603642/2818869)、なんてことになります。

どうせタイマー監視するならと、[DOMContentLoaded を使わず head 要素が作成されるのを待ってみました](https://jsfiddle.net/0xvxcu7f/2/)が、やはりリソースの読み込みは行われるようで…。

### 外部リソースを読み込ませない

基本的にJavascriptからブラウザの通信機能をどうこうすることはできません。通信の横取りなんて危険なことはもちろん、単にブロックすることもできません。

[iframe要素のsandbox属性](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox)を使えば別オリジンからのリソースをブロックできますが、同一オリジンを制限することはできません。

ページ単位では [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy) というものがあり、ページの作者が意図しないリソース読み込み・実行を禁止することができます。HTTPヘッダやmetaタグでホワイトリストを指定するのですが、[このmetaタグはJavascriptで挿入しても効果があります](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28366917/2818869)。が、読み込みが開始される前に挿入しなければなりません。

iframeのDOMを通して、外部リソースのURLをダミーのものに置き換える、という方法でも同様です。ただ、通信は発生しても見えなければいいということなら、この方法が使えるかもしれません。

またCSP用のmetaタグ挿入、外部リソースの除去、どちらにせよ iframe のDOMにアクセスするわけですが、そのためには同一オリジンもしくはCORSの設定が行われていないといけません。で、その条件を満たしているなら XMLHttpRequest でHTMLだけ取得したほうが簡単でしょう。

あとはサーバーサイドのプログラムと組み合わせるか、ですね。

Answer (score 1):

iframeのsrcに直接URLを書かずに、一旦JavaScriptで`http://example.com/sample.html`のソースを取得し、その中の非同期通信をするエレメント(link、srcの付いたscript、iframe、img)を削除してから、`contentDocument.write()`などでiframeの中に書き込んでやるのはどうでしょうか。エレメントそのものではなく、srcなどの属性だけを消してもいいと思います。

Comment: kaitoy さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。
「一旦JavaScriptでhttp://example.com/sample.htmlのソースを取得し」の部分が出来ないのです。。
example.comは別ドメインなのでAjax(XMLHTTP)でばオリジン制限がかかっていて取得が出来ません。
ソースを取得する方法はございますでしょうか？

Comment: `<script id="hoge" src="http://example.com/sample.html" type="text/html"></script>`みたいにして、`document.getElementById('hoge')`から取り出せるかと思ったのですが、なんだか取り出せません。HTMLソースのダウンロードはしているようなのですが。というかもっと正攻法があるのかもしれませんが。

Comment: `<script>`の`src`でとってきたものを[取得する方法はない](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148441/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-the-file-specified-as-the-src-of-a-script-tag)ようです。手詰まりました。